# Appcelerator tableView font color

Tags: android, titanium, tableview, appcelerator

How can you set the color of the font for the rows in tableView?

I DO NOT want to set it row by row like this:

```
var table_data = [
    {title:'Row 1', color: 'black'},
];
```

I have tried adding font:{colour:'black'} to the table var but it does not seem to work. Like this:

```
var table1 =  Titanium.UI.createTableView({
  data:table_data,
  separatorColor:'black',
  font:{color:'black'}
});
```

I want to be able to set it so any row in the table has a set color. Specifically as I will be adding items to the table and I want them to be 'black' not the default white/grey. So when I add new items they will be black...

I am sure this is simple but I cant seem to find anything that is assisting me hence the question here

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go.Add a lable in tableview row and set it according to your own desire

```
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    title : 'Saved Locations'
});
var data = [];
var tabLoc = Ti.UI.createTableView({
});
self.add(tabLoc);
var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height : '60dp',
    className : "tableRow",
});
var labTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color : 'black',
    font : {
        fontSize : '12dp',
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    text : 'There is no location yet saved',
    textAlign : 'center'
});

row.add(labTitle);
data.push(row)
tabLoc.setData(data);
self.open()
```

Thanks

Comment: This won't work if there is a search control attached to the tableview